cmake, TARGET was not created in this directory
I have two custom commands, do things for my target.
After linking my application, I need to about 4 commands to do extra processing on my ELF file.
For me this is a 'boiler plate' that occurs for every ELF we build. I want this in a directory with a bunch of other "boiler plate CMAKE code".
So in that director/Cmake file - I have
   add_custom_command( TARGET 
                         foo.elf POST_BUILD 
                       COMMAND
                         blah blah blah
                       COMMAND
                         blah blah blah
                       COMMAND
                         blah blah blah
                       WORKING_DIRECTORY
                         ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
                       VERBATIM
 )

The problem is that the ELF is defined and created in a different CMAKE file and cmake issues an error:
TARGET 'foo.elf' was not created in this directory'

Why does this need to be created in this CMakeList.txt file? I know the target is created in a different CMakefile in a different directory. so why does it have to be here?
Any idea how to work around this?
Is there a way to tell CMAKE - "this target was built in another CMakefile"?

I think you need first create the target then add the subdirectory, for example:
# in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
add_executable (${BIN_NAME})
add_subdirectory (data)
add_subdirectory (src)

Then, after the custom command created we need to create a new target as a dependency for our main target, for example:
# in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data
find_program (GCR "glib-compile-resources" NO_CACHE)

if (NOT GCR)
    message (FATAL_ERROR "glib-compile-resources no fue encontrado.")
else()
    message ("glib-compile-resources: ${GCR}")
    add_custom_command (
        OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/resources.c"
        DEPENDS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/resources.gresource.xml"
        COMMAND ${GCR} --sourcedir="${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data" --target="${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/resources.c" --generate-source "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/resources.gresource.xml"
    )
    add_custom_target (compile-resources DEPENDS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/resources.c")
    add_dependencies (${BIN_NAME} compile-resources)
    target_sources (${BIN_NAME} PRIVATE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/resources.c")
endif ()

So, in my example before going to src subdirectory, cmake first create resources.c and then add it to the sources chain for the compilation process. Same process if you need something POST_BUILD.

I do that in a different cmake file that is processed before this file I have about 10 source directories and one common cmake scripts directory where I keep common cmake things common to all executables I am creating

Is it possible show us your CMakeLists.txt code?

Which one? There are about 10.. At tehe top I have a CMakeLists.txt file, it does about 5 add_subdirectory() calls, and some sub directories then include further sub directories,  this is not easy for me to 'sanitize' for public display and discussion as these are sort of large.

To be honest, in your original post you give us too little information about what's going on in your computer. So, the more code you gave us the more we can detect the bug or error.

yea, I have ben fighting cmake and growing increasingly pissed at the language. I find it obtuse, hard to understand and confusing.  I've been writing C, Makefiles, SH, Bash, done lots of autoconfig stuff, Perl and Python since the early 80s... and I find cmake is so weird and hard to get my head around. At times the syntax defies all logic.
